# Assign values of a new column based on the frequency of a special pattern in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to create another column of a data frame that groups each member in the first column based on the order.

Here is a reproducible demo:

```
df1=c("Alex","23","ID #:123", "John","26","ID #:564")
df1=data.frame(df1)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% mutate(group= ifelse(df1 %like% "ID #:",1,NA ) )
```

This was the output from the demo:

```
df1        group
1     Alex    NA
2       23    NA
3 ID #:123     1
4     John    NA
5       26    NA
6 ID #:564     1
```

This is what I want:

```
 df1         group
 1     Alex     1
 2       23     1
 3 ID #:123     1
 4     John     2
 5       26     2
 6 ID #:564     2
```

So I want to have a group column indicates each member in order.

I appreciate in advance for any reply or thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift the condition with `lag` first and then do a `cumsum`:

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate(group= cumsum(lag(df1 %like% "ID #:", default = 1)))

#       df1 group
#1     Alex     1
#2       23     1
#3 ID #:123     1
#4     John     2
#5       26     2
#6 ID #:564     2
```

---

Details:

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate(
        # calculate the condition
        cond = df1 %like% "ID #:", 
        # shift the condition down and fill the first value with 1
        lag_cond = lag(cond, default = 1),
        # increase the group when the condition is TRUE (ID encountered)
        group= cumsum(lag_cond))

#       df1  cond lag_cond group
#1     Alex FALSE     TRUE     1
#2       23 FALSE    FALSE     1
#3 ID #:123  TRUE    FALSE     1
#4     John FALSE     TRUE     2
#5       26 FALSE    FALSE     2
#6 ID #:564  TRUE    FALSE     2
```

Comment: Awesome solution! I didn't think about using "lag()"  and "cumsum()" in this case! It works perfectly! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention whether you're always expecting 3 rows per member. This code will allow you to toggle the number of rows per member (in case there's not always 3):

```
# Your code:
df1=c("Alex","23","ID #:123", "John","26","ID #:564")
df1=data.frame(df1)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% mutate(group= ifelse(df1 %like% "ID #:",1,NA ) )

number_of_rows_per_member <- 3 # Change if necessary
positions <- 1:(nrow(df1)/number_of_rows_per_member)

group <- c()
for (i in 1:length(positions)) { 
  group[(i*number_of_rows_per_member):((i*number_of_rows_per_member)-(number_of_rows_per_member-1))] <- i
  }
group # This is the group column

df1$group <- group # Now just move the group coloumn into your original dataframe
df1 # Done!
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! This is amazing!